# How to check 2 column values in a sql table aren't duplicated

Tags: python, sql

I attached a `src` database to a `destination`. Each database contains the columns `time` and `id`. I want to check that there is no row in `src` that has the same `time, id` pair as the one in `destination`.

I tried the following query:

```
    select (s.time, s.id)
    from src.table_name as s
    where (s.time, s.id) in (select (d.time, d.id) from table_name as d)
    limit 1
```

but it says `E         OperationalError: sub-select returns 1 columns - expected 2`. I also tried

```
    select (s.time, s.id)
    from src.table_name as s
    where (s.time, s.id) in (select d.time, d.id from table_name as d)
    limit 1
```

and now it says
`E         OperationalError: row value misused`

Is the correct syntax

```
    select s.time, s.id
    from src.table_name as s
    where (s.time, s.id) in (select d.time, d.id from table_name as d)
    limit 1
```

?

This seems to work, but I'm not totally sure this is doing what I want it to do.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: A [mcve] would make this much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JOIN` instead of `IN (subquery)`

```
SELECT s.time, s.id
FROM src.table_name as s
JOIN table_name AS d ON s.time = d.time AND s.id = d.id
LIMIT 1
```